# Tomcat SSL adds overhead to the response time - Running as Springboot embeded container

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat7

I have been running spring boot based microservices on embedded tomcat container. The actual response is generated in 5 ms(Time captured within my application code.that is  Start Time - End Time), but when I see through curl, it's taking 250 ms. Around 245 ms overhead.

Anybody faced this behavior with spring boot embedded tomcat. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

### UPDATE

The latency I see is from the SSL handshake. We use HTTPS REST end points, we are seeing around 200 ms is being spent for app connect (time_appconnect). Any suggestions?

Any suggestions?

Comment: If it only occurs inside a docker container, shouldn't the title be "Docker adds overhead..."?

Comment: Cache connection.

Comment: I suggest you close that question and rewrite it property as it escalated quickly from tomcat, docker, to ssl handshake so it is just unclear and misleading now.

Comment: You are correct. The SSL handshake takes time. It is amortised over subsequent connections by SSL session resumption. Timing merely one request doesn't tell the whole story. In any case there is nothing you can do about it. NB SSL is implemented by Java, not by Tomcat.